# Using *gin.Context in cron Job

Tags: go, cron

I have cron job that will call function that require *gin.Context as statement, this statement will be required int other process in the other next step. Previously I had made my code like this:

```
    _, _ = c.cr.AddFunc(constant.CronRunningAt(8), func() {
        ctx := &gin.Context{}
        c.loan.LoanRepaymentNotification(ctx)
    })
```

but it throw error like this:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x38 pc=0x100d154f4]
```

[image]

Is there any way to generate value type *gin.Context that can be passed to the function called? Thank you

Comment: Why does this function require a *gin.Context?  That doesn't really make sense outside of a web service.  Can your cron job instead call an internal function that does the thing you actually need?

Comment: Actually because it will call the existing event driven func that require *gin.Context, but I decided to refactor the code and make the proper way to replace the event driven. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use this method on a cron task, then it means that **must not** use `gin.Context`.
As it is specified on library documentation:

> Gin is a web framework written in Go.

So what you want to do with `gin.Context` could be achieve by another way, thanks to the `context.Context` for exemple.
It depends of what you want to do at the end, but you should refactoring your code by changing `LoanRepaymentNotification` or its underlying methods to use only `context.Context` on your cron job.

Comment: Yes it is, previously I choose to use *gin.Context is because it will call other existing func that require input from *gin.Context as statement. But now I find the proper way to solve it and I just just refactor my code, then it working properly without requiring *gin.Context anymore. Thanks